# How to specify npm dependency as github subfolder url?

Tags: git, github, npm

My git repository:

```
README.md
packages
  common
    package.json
  main
    package.json
```

How to specify `common` dependency in `main` package.json as github subfolder url?

This does not work `"common": "git://github.com/<user>/<project>/packages/common.git"`

Answer (score 12):

It looks like this is not supported by NPM, and the NPM team appears to have no interest in supporting this functionality.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974

Comment: Very unfortunate this is not supported... So I need to create a repository for every package....

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). in short you are telling get to look for this folder in the following repo.

to do this, execute the following command:

```
git submodule add git://github.com/<user>/<project>/packages/common.git packages/common
```

notice that when cloning the repo you need to recursively clone it to be able to download the submodules:

```
git clone --recursive <your-git-url>
```

Comment: When I do `git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/<project>/packages/common.git` from local dir <project>/packages/common and then `git push -u origin master` I get an error `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/<user>/<project>/packages/common.git/' not found`

Comment: `git remote add` is different than `git submodule add` what you did by `git remote add origin ....`  is replaced your original remote by this one, now you are trying to push to another repo.