# With npm can I depend on a git branch rather than scoped package from a monorepo

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a project which depends on an scoped npm module from (lerna) monorepo:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@as-pect/cli": "^5.0.0"
},
```

However, there is a bug in the latest release, which is fixed on the following branch:

https://github.com/jtenner/as-pect/tree/as-minor-upgrade

I would like to substitute `^5.0.0` for a reference to the head of this branch. However, for this to work, I need to reference both the branch and the subfolder. I've tried the following:

git@github.com:jtenner/as-pect.git#as-minor-upgrade/packages/cli/

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Depend on a branch or tag using a git URL in a package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350673/depend-on-a-branch-or-tag-using-a-git-url-in-a-package-json)

Comment: No, it doesn't - I need to depend on a subfolder within a branch or a tag, it's an additional level of complexity!

Comment: It looks like that isn't possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679799/how-to-specify-npm-dependency-as-github-subfolder-url